# Error Connecting to F28379D board using XDS100V2 debugger in rational test real time(RTRT)

Tags: rtrt

Launching JTAG Debugger
SEVERE: Could not open session. Found 5 devices matching: .*
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/C28xx_CPU1
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/CPU1_CLA1
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/C28xx_CPU2
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/CPU2_CLA1
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/IcePick_C_0
org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.ti.ccstudio.scripting.environment.ScriptingException: Could not open session. Found 5 devices matching: .*
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/C28xx_CPU1
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/CPU1_CLA1
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/C28xx_CPU2
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/CPU2_CLA1
Texas Instruments XDS100v2 USB Debug Probe_0/IcePick_C_0 (ti_tdp.js#25)

Tries updating TDP file for removing extra devices but didnt worked.